# Binding project for UltraliteJNI12.jar - "already defines a member" error

Tags: xamarin.android

We need to use a Sybase Ultralite database in our Mono for Android app (it's a port of an existing application, synchronising with a Sybase server database).

I'm not aware of an existing Mono binding, so I'm setting off on the task of creating a binding library using the new project type in 4.2.

So... I've added UltraliteJNI12.jar, set its  build action to InputJar, and clicked 'build'.

I get an error: 
Com.Ianywhere.Ultralitejni12.Implementation.JniDbMgr' already defines a member called 'Release' with the same parameter types

and yes, when I look at the generated source, there are two identical Release members declared.

Is there a way of working round this? I've read the tutorial and can't see anything there which points to a solution.

Thanks, and apologies for what may be a stupid question - I'm just starting out on this!

James

Answer (score 1):

The answer - as supplied by Jonathan Pryor on the Mono for Android list - was to rename one of the instances of release, by adding the following to *metadata.xml*:

```
 <attr
  path="/api/package[@name='com.ianywhere.ultralitejni12.implementation']/class  [@name='JniDbMgr']/method[@name='release']"
  name="managedName">Release2
</attr>
```